# problems using 'header' in php to redirect on load

Tags: php, redirect, header

No headers are already sent, this is the first piece of code accessed on the page.

I am making a multilingual site and as it has very little text am trying to redirect users to different directories based on their language. I have written this in `php` and every time I assess the site, I receive an error and it wont load.

```
$lang=$_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE'];
$es=array("es", "es-es", "es-us", "es-mx");

if(array_key_exists($es, $lang)){
header('Location: http://www.site.com/es');
exit;
}else{
header('Location: http://www.site.com');
exit;
}
```

In Firefox I receive the error ***'Firefox has detected that the server is redirecting the request for this address in a way that will never complete.'***

And in Safari ***'Too many redirects occurred trying to open "websitename". This occurs when opening a page it redirects you to another that, when opened, you are redirected to another page.'***

But I have no copy of the language check script in the sub folder. When I make the if statement very simple *`if($lang =='es-es')`* it works perfectly. There must be something wrong with my syntax but I can't see what it is.

Comment: This is normally happens when you are redirecting to a page, which is already redirecting to somewhere else, and this goes on and on.. May be you are putting this condition check on the page and redirecting to the page itself. This may cause executing the script everytime and it kinda sets and infinite loop of the redirection...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `in_array` to check instead - or turn your dictionary array into a hash:

1)

```
if (in_array($lang, $es)){
  // ...
}
```

2)

```
$es = array_flip(array("es", "es-es", "es-us", "es-mx"));
if (isset($es[$lang])) {
  // ...
}
```

As it stands, your `$es` array is an indexed one, but you're trying to search in its *keys* - which are simple numbers (0, 1, 2, 3...).

Yet there's another problem here. What if someone tries to access your `site.com` without any variation of `es` in `HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE` header? They will be redirected to it again... and again... and again, as each subsequent redirect is *re-checked* by that `if` clause.

The solution is to make some default page, which *won't* be checked for that language setting; thus the eternal redirection loop will be broken. )

Comment: Hey, that was the command I used first and the same effect :(

Comment: I didn't even see that! I've broken the loop now but the problem is that my browsers have 'es-es' (confirmed with vardump) and they are still being redirected to the english side

Comment: Ok, can you include to your question the dump of `$_SERVER['HTTP_ACCEPT_LANGUAGE']`?

Answer (score 2):

As I understood, correct me if wrong, if you are on the ELSE statement, it redirects you to the same site, where the check is performed once again, and redirects you once again, and again, causing an endless loop.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `in_array` instead of `array_key_exists`

First, try to do this:
`var_dump("<pre>", $lang); die();` 
and see what are you actually getting in `$lang`.

What every you are getting, copy past it into your `$es` array values.

Answer (score 0):

It is saying so because you are redirecting it to the same page again and again. try redirecting to some other page if your condition gets false or simply `alert` a message saying language do not found or something like this.

Answer (score 0):

As I Getting your Problem...

Change these two lines

```
         $es=array("es", "es-es", "es-us", "es-mx");

          if(array_key_exists($es, $lang)){
```

with following lines

```
  $es=array("es"=>es, "es-es"=>es-es, "es-us"=>es-us, "es-mx"=>es-mx);

    if(array_key_exists($lang, $es)){
```

Basically In the **array_keys_exits($key, $array-name)** function there are two parameter pass & it is to be first parameter is the value of (key) you want to search or Second parameter is pass the Array name.

I Think you pass the array_key_exits with null value as key & wrong syntax description.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-key-exists.php